does ある and いる have つもりform and volitional form?
I cant find the answer because everywhere its different. I always have problem with ある　and いる because sometimes you cant use it with some grammar. I would be very grateful if someone could explain this. Thank You

What do you mean by "つもり form"?

I mean for example 書くつもりです、するつもりです

I think we call that the "dictionary form". ある and いる already are in the dictionary form.

@GuiImamura He probably asks if it is natural to use 「…あるつもりだ。」, 「…いるつもりだ。」.

Volitional for ある is あろう and for いる is いよう。

Could you specify which exactly functions あろう and いよう can have (e.g. from this list)? I think that I have read somewhere that this sufffix when used with existential verbs (e.g. ある, いる) can only mean conjecture (推測) "probably is / exists / has", and not intention ("wants to be / exist / have") or suggestion ("let's be / exist / have").

The list you posted sugests that this よう is an auxiliary verb, which is something I've never thought about before, and I'm not sure if I wanna agree with, since it works with some verbs but not others (e.g. it works with いる and あげる but not with ある or やる), and I've always seen it as part of verb conjugation. If you try any decent auto-conjugator (i.e. like this) you'll see it's part of the verb itself, not an auxiliary verb.

@Arfrever Anyway yes, the only valid use of volitional あろう that comes to my mind is after the で particle, and both あろう and いよう after で has the "let's be (something/someway)" meaning. However, いよう also works without a preceding で and can mean "let's stay" (as in このままでいよう), or can be used as an auxiliary verb, as in 笑っていよう which translates to " let's be smiling" (to which you can add a ずっと = "for ever", for example).

I just realized that this よう is the volitional conjugation for all ichidan-verbs, while godan-verbs have another rule for conjugating. Which is why it works for いる and あげる but not for ある and やる, and further leads me to the conclusion that it is NOT an auxiliary verb

@Arfrever Just realized my example has a preceding で, so here's another example: 学校にいよう

In my question, I meant ある and いる used as lexical verbs, not as part of any grammatical constructions (like extended copula である, VERB〜てある, VERB〜ている). Regarding classification, I consider this -ō ~ -yō to be one of several suffixes of verbs, not as independent auxiliary verb. -ō ~ -yō developed from Old Japanese suffixes -am- + -u. Japanese Wiktionary probably more or less follows traditional analysis of Japanese grammar.

@Arfrever Yes but that article lists it as a 助動詞. Please correct me if I'm wrong (I learned Japanese naturally, not from textbooks, and left Japan early) but I believe that to be "auxiliary verb"; I'll also need you to be more didactic on your " am- + -u" example. And, no valid use of ある in volitional form comes to my mind, without the preceding で.

E.g. for verb kaku: modern kakō comes, through some intermediate forms, from Old Japanese kakamu. There were several forms ending with -u: kaku, kakanu (negative), kakamu (conjectural), kakyemu (past conjectural), kakayu (passive), kakaru (passive) etc. Western linguists consider that that final -u is actually suffix of conclusive/terminal (終止形), and that some part before -u is another suffix. E.g. negative form kakanu is segmented as kak- + -an- + -u, and -an- is the suffix giving negative meaning to that form. Similarly for kakamu = kak- + -am- + -u.
